# transpose based on join in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Personal_Details table

```
name   age
john   25
nikita 29
```

Sports table:

```
name   games
john   basketball
john   volleyball
john   football
nikita skating
```

Desired output:

```
name   games1     games2     games3
john   basketball volleyball football
nikita skating    null       null
```

i want to join both tables if there is match based on name variable then return the values of games 
in new variable .
Let me know any suggestions how to achieve this!!

Comment: Do you know the number of columns that you want in the result set?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to concatenate text from multiple rows into a single text string in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/how-to-concatenate-text-from-multiple-rows-into-a-single-text-string-in-sql-serv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a known or maximum number of columns, you can perform a simple PIVOT in concert with row_number()

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([name] varchar(50),[games] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('john','basketball')
,('john','volleyball')
,('john','football')
,('nikita','skating')

Select *
 From  (
        Select [Name] 
              ,[Games]
              ,[Col]   = concat('games',row_number() over (partition by [name] order by [games]))
         From @YourTable
       ) src
 Pivot ( max([Games]) for Col in ([Games1],[Games2],[Games3],[Games4]) ) pvt
```

**Returns**

```
Name    Games1      Games2      Games3      Games4
john    basketball  football    volleyball  NULL
nikita  skating     NULL        NULL        NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest method is to aggregate the values into a *string* rather than in separate columns.  This is not exactly what you are asking for but it might do what you want:

```
select name, string_agg(game, ',') as games
from sports
group by name;
```

Comment: Yes @Gordon it is working thanks.But can suggest how do i put the values in separate columns